# How to find out what is port number Arduino is plugged Into

Tags: linux, arduino

I need to specify it as PORT_NAMES in http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Java code. 
Also where is /jre/lib/ and /jre/lib/ext directories located?

Comment: Hi there, your question does not provide enough information to begin to answer! You need to provide more information such as what operating system you are using. You could try searching google for something like the following: "find com port in use windows 7"

Answer (score 0):

Control panel, system, you should see your Arduino in the list of hardware. Right click and check the properties. The port to which is connected is there.